# Google Tag Manager: Triggering an event if the DOM contains a certain css class

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a gallery of products that each belong to a specific brand. In order to track down how many impressions/reach the brands generate I was thinking about using GTM, having a trigger on DOM load or pageview, and have it read a specific class "brandlink" for the text inside this element. This way if the page loads products from Amazon, eBay and Walmart, each pageview would trigger multiple events, one for each brand, with the label = their_brand_name.

In a very similar fashion as to how ads are tracking the number of impressions they generate.

I can clearly see the "Click classes" variable, but not something that reads the text inside a class, without a click being necessary.

Pointers? Different approach? Thank you!

Comment: The most stable way I can think of would be to create a custom javascript tag. Within the javascript you can use document.getElementsByClassName to get an array of objects you need. Now iterate all results and bring them in a meaningful order like enhanced ecommerce view data. With enhanced ecommerce you only need one helper request, not n-requests for each identified object. After your objects are all identified and available as a correct enhanced ecommerce object send them with a helper event to GA.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to create a trigger that uses the `DOM Element` variable type.

[image]

You can see how the Variable configuration uses the element ID (alternatively, you could use CSS selector method). And then in the Trigger configuration, you can it to fire on DOM ready if that particular DOM element exists and has a certain value (if you have more than one value, you could use a regex matching pattern).

Comment: DOM Element with CSS selector works very well for a single value. I'm not sure how to go ahead with multiple ones, as I want to trigger an Event for each element it grabs. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to use DOM variable if you want to select click element by special css-selector, just write {{variable}} instead this selector in css-match input field